# How can we create array of list of column and it’s value by iterating on columns of table in snowflake

Tags: arrays, dataframe, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, explode

Convert given pyspark code to snowflake compatible code

```
df=df.withColumn(“array_mode”,
                 f.explode(f.array([f.array([f.lit(cl),f.col(cl)]) 
                        for cl in df.columns[5:]])]
               )
```

I tried using array_constructor

Comment: Hi - please update your question with sample data and the result you are trying to achieve. Also show your attempt using ARRAY_CONSTRUCTOR

Comment: Are you looking for the SQL equivalent or trying to get the pyspark to run as python in Snowflake?

Comment: SQL equivalent but python in snowflake will also work